# What are these types?

Tags: c++

I was reading through the boost documentation on tuples and came across the following valid tuple instantiation (A, B and C are some user defined classes):

```
tuple<A, int(*)(char, int), B(A::*)(C&), C>
```

I couldn't understand what the types of the 2nd and 3rd parameters were. What exactly are the `int(*)(char, int)` and `B(A::*)(C&)` types?

Comment: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html That's for C; C++ adds pointer-to-member and template types but the idea stays. Have a read (but be aware that people don't use that in production code, there's `typedef` for simplifying such declarations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int(*)(char, int)
```

Is a pointer to a function accepting a `char` and an `int` as parameter and returning an `int`.

```
B(A::*)(C&)
```

Is a pointer to a member function on an `A` object, returning `B` and accepting a reference to `C` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea what the second one meant. +1

Answer (score 2):

`int(*)(char, int)` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and takes a `char` and an `int` as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int(*)(char, int)
> ```

A pointer to function taking `(char, int)` and returning `int`.

> ```
> B(A::*)(C&)
> ```

A pointer to member function of `A` taking `C&` returning `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
B(A::*)(C&)
```

is a pointer to member function ( member of `A`) that takes a `C&` and returns a `B`

Example:

```
class B{
public:
/*empty class*/
};
class A{
public:
 B DoSomething( C& input){
 return B;
}

}
int main(){
auto G = &A::DoSomething;
}
```

the type of `G` is `B(A::*)(C&)`

Answer (score 0):

`B(A::*)(C&)` is a pointer to `A`'s member function taking a `C` reference parameter and returning a `B` object.

Luchian already answered for `int(*)(char, int)`.